# How to replace every second element in array?

Tags: java

How can I improve my code? Every second step I need to replace elements:

```
String replace (String s){
        String result;
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                char c = chars[i];
            for (int j = i+1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                char tmp = c;
                c = chars[j];
                chars[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        result = new String(chars);
        return result;
```

Comment: if you start with `"abcde"`, what should the result be?

Comment: return "cbeda" firstly a replace with c, then a with e. My task replace every 2 element in array

Comment: OK. What about `"abcdef"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to do it in one line:

```
String replace(String s) {
    return s.substring(1).replaceAll("(.)(.)", "$2$1") + s.charAt(0);
}
```

The algorithm may be done in one pass by recognising that it's equivalent to moving the first character to the end and swap each remaining pair of chars.

Answer (score 0):

Well, make the for loop go up by 2

```
String replace (String s){
    String result;
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2)//Here we are incrementing i by 2 {
            char c = chars[i];
            char tmp = c;
            chars[i] = tmp;
    }
    result = new String(chars);
    return result;
```